# Tables with identical styles have different widths

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I am trying to style two tables similarly. However, the column widths are different between the two tables even though the styles are the same. There seems to be invisible padding or spacing in the second table's first column.

```js
document.getElementById('displayDateTime').innerHTML = Date();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: green;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
pre {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.input {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.lineno {
  background-color: grey;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.output {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="code-block">
  <h2>Displaying Date &amp; Time</h2>

  <h3>Input</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <pre class="lineno">1<br>2<br>3</pre>
      </td>
      <td>
        <pre class="input">
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;
   document.getElementById('displayDateTime').innerHTML = Date();
&lt;/script&gt;</pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h3>Output</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <pre class="lineno">&gt;</pre>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id="displayDateTime" class="output"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: I would argue this is not an appropriate use for a `table` as you are not presenting tabular data at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to add this:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

References:

- [The `table-layout` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) ~ MDN
- [17.5.2 Table width algorithms: the `table-layout` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#width-layout) ~ W3C

```js
document.getElementById('displayDateTime').innerHTML = Date();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: green;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
pre {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.input {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.lineno {
  background-color: grey;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.output {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="code-block">
  <h2>Displaying Date &amp; Time</h2>
  <h3>Input</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <pre class="lineno">1<br>2<br>3</pre>
      </td>
      <td>
        <pre class="input">
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;
   document.getElementById('displayDateTime').innerHTML = Date();
&lt;/script&gt;</pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <h3>Output</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <pre class="lineno">&gt;</pre>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p id="displayDateTime" class="output"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about `table-layout: fixed`. However, I would not like them to be 50% width. I would like the left column to only take the space of the text + 15px padding on both sides.

Comment: You can adjust the widths. Check the references.

Comment: Yup that did it! Thank you!